# neo4j - Better way of creating nodes having same type

Tags: neo4j

I am new to `neo4j`. I am writing a script that imports records from `MySQL` to `neo4j`. I want to know the better way of creating nodes that have same type. I have created nodes related to **likes** as, consider following snippet:

```
CREATE (Like:like_1 { 'node_type:"likes", like_name:"abc" })
CREATE (Like:like_2 { 'node_type:"likes", like_name:"def" })
CREATE (Like:like_3 { 'node_type:"likes", like_name:"ghi" })
```

And in the similar fashion I created **users**:

```
CREATE (User:user_1 { 'node_type:"user", user_name:"alpha" })
CREATE (User:user_2 { 'node_type:"user", user_name:"beta" })
CREATE (User:user_3 { 'node_type:"user", user_name:"gamma" })
```

Thus, total 6 nodes were created, where, (like_*n* and user_*n*) *n* is the `id` (primary key) of SQL record. I thought, it is better for the retrieval, such that the label of node is known to me (like_ followed by id).

```
MATCH (l:like_1) RETURN l
```

Is the way nodes created above better? Or I should go the following (alternate) pattern, in which I put `id` as a property in node:

```
CREATE (Like:like { 'node_type:"likes", like_name:"abc", like_id:"1" })
CREATE (Like:like { 'node_type:"likes", like_name:"def", like_id:"2" })
CREATE (Like:like { 'node_type:"likes", like_name:"ghi", like_id:"3" })
CREATE (User:user { 'node_type:"user", like_name:"alpha", user_id:"1" })
CREATE (User:user { 'node_type:"user", like_name:"beta", user_id:"2" })
CREATE (User:user { 'node_type:"user", like_name:"gamma", user_id:"3" })
```

Carrying with the same scenario, if the second apparoach is better, how could I make relationships betweens two `user_1` and all `likes` and retrieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to reread parts of the Cypher dev guide, or at least the parts on node labeling, and using variables in your queries.

In short, though, the syntax is `(variableName:nodeLabel {<params>})`

nodeLabel is the equivalent of a type or a table in a relational db, so it makes sense to `User` as a node label, but not `user_1`.

variableName only lasts for the duration of a query. It binds the element (or elements) to that variable for use later in the query. If you aren't planning on using the variable for anything in the rest of the query, don't use a variable at all.

For unique identifiers (like your id primary key), you'll want to set that as a property on your nodes, and additionally create a unique constraint on that label/property combination (that's the equivalent of a unique constraint on a column in a table).

As for Likes...I've got to ask, does a Like make more sense as a node, or as a relationship? Do Users like each other (and other things)? How does a Like fit into your data model?

Rather than just look at your db and try to translate it directly to neo4j, you might want to draw out or refer to an entity relationship diagram or similar. In neo4j, the physical model IS the logical model, so going from a diagram to the actual db should be easy.

For example, let's say that it makes more sense to model Likes as a relationship between users. You might do that like this:

```
MERGE (user1:User { id:1, name:"alpha" })
MERGE (user2:User { id:2, name:"beta" })
MERGE (user1)-[:Likes]->(user2)
```

In the above I'm using MERGE instead of CREATE so that if I run this again, it won't create duplicate nodes or relationships (you'll want to read up on MERGE, it's useful but tricky, you'll usually want to use it piecemeal, not for an entire pattern). The nodes I created are nodes with the :User label. The id is a property (and you really should create a constraint on the id property of the User label before doing any create script). After the two nodes are created we create the relationship between them.

An alternate approach, rather than doing node creation and label creation all at once, is to separate them. This also makes sense if you're tracking your Likes in a separate table.

You would create your nodes similarly, but without variables, like this:

```
MERGE (:User { id:1, name:"alpha" })
MERGE (:User { id:2, name:"beta" })
```

And in your separate query, adding the Likes relationship, assuming you have the ids of the users and assuming there's a unique constraint on the ids of Users:

```
MATCH (aUser:User{ id:1})
MATCH (bUser:User{ id:2})
MERGE (aUser)-[:Likes]->(bUser)
```

Remember, variables are only in-scope for the duration of the query to help you refer to and use already defined elements elsewhere in the query.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. For your question, think `Likes` as an `Ingredient`, user may like or dislike an ingredient or many. There is no relationship like "likes" between users.

Comment: Ah, got it, hope my answer is still useful even with that bad assumption.